# Dynamically select the element from the list of elements based on child index

Tags: javascript, css, selenium, css-selectors, webdriver-io

I need to fetch the field/element on the form for my automation code dynamically. There are multiple fields on the form and based on some particular index that is dynamic I want to fetch that element.

Thus how can I pass this column child index dynamically to the helper method to fetch the desired dynamic fields?

Selector list looks like below:

I tried something like this which does not work:

`'ul li:nth-child(${index}'`

Throw following error:

> invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified

Answer (score -2):

I just need to use [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) around the selector instead of single quotes.

`` `ul li:nth-child(${index})` ``